# .NET Core - Filter data by custom permissions

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

I have a system where besides roles we have permissions to exact data. For example user has permission to Book A but doesn't have - to book B - so they don't see it in a list. We manage it using db tables where we store all the permissions.
So method of getting a list of objects looks something like this:

```
GetList().Where(x => x.Permissions.Any(p => p.CanRead && p.UserId == userId))
```

I am not sure if this is a good approach cause this code should be placed in every service (even if we add specification there). But can't think of anything else. Is this a good approach?
Also this approach gives me trouble when I try to use the same service for our schedule service which of course doesn't have a user and any permissions. How can I work around this?

Comment: What you're looking for "resource-based authorization". The docs cover this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thank you! That is very helpful. But is there an option to check permissions before getting a list of data from repository? Like in my service this check is done before calling ToList() from IQueryable. Cause my server won't survive loading all data from a table each time.

Comment: That's just geared to the example. You can pass whatever you want to the handler, and use whatever logic you need to in the handler to determine whether the user is authorized or not. Since you'll likely be needing to query inside the handler at that point (at least for the permission set), see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/dependencyinjection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @ChrisPratt Excuse me for tagging you for this old question but there's something I can't uderstand. How do you apply the resource authorization to a list of entities? I mean, how to authorize the user to only see all the entities of a type he can access? The resource authorization shown in the docs only works on a resource. For example, I would like to get all the resources that logged user owns. Don't really know if the "authorization" and the retrieval of data should be splitted. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a list view, the user is either authorized or not, so standard authorization works there. Then, the whole idea of resourced based authorization is that the user "owns" certain entities, which then means there's something to query on, i.e. a foreign key. So, you just filter the list of all entities by entities belonging to the specific user. If there's none, they get an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Base on the Document Chris Pratt post, I suggest you use this authorization :

```
Task<AuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user,
                          object resource,
                          IEnumerable<IAuthorizationRequirement> requirements);
Task<AuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user,
                          object resource,
                          string policyName);
```

I have an example in View to display button 'View' for book A but not for Book B below:

First, I have 3 roles ("Admin", "User", "Staff") - Role Admin can read both book A and B but role Staff only can read book A. Then, when a staff login, AuthorizationService will check permission 'READ' and if that staff doesnt has permisson read Book B, button 'View' wont appear  :

```
@if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "STAFF", Operations.Read)).Succeeded)
        {
            <div>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button id="btnRead" class="form-control btn-info">View</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

And, in page Role you also need a table to assign each permission to every book. You account admin , and for each role there is a tree or table display all books categories, each book category will have checkbox 'Read', 'Delete', 'Create'. Then if you check box 'Delete' bookB in role 'Staff', then all staff account will have permission to delete book B. Hope this help !